# unexpected behaviour in this program in python

Tags: python, function, output

I have this code to calculate minimum number of coins from a sum with given list of denomiations.
for eg :  `minimum change for 69 with denomiations [25,10,5,1]  :  [25, 25, 10, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

```
def get_min_coin_configuration(sum=None, coins=None, cache={}):
    #if cache == None:  # this is quite crucial if its in the definition its presistent ...
    #    cache = {}
    if sum in cache:
        return cache[sum]
    elif sum in coins:  # if sum in coins, nothing to do but return.
        cache[sum] = [sum]
        return cache[sum]
    elif min(coins) > sum:  # if the largest coin is greater then the sum, there's nothing we can do.
        #cache[sum] = []
        #return cache[sum]
        return []
    else:  # check for each coin, keep track of the minimun configuration, then return it.
        min_length = 0
        min_configuration = []
        for coin in coins:
            results = get_min_coin_configuration(sum - coin, coins, cache)
            if results != []:
                if min_length == 0 or (1 + len(results)) < len(min_configuration):
                    #print "min config", min_configuration
                    min_configuration = [coin] + results
                    #print "min config", min_configuration
                    min_length = len(min_configuration)
                    cache[sum] = min_configuration
        return cache[sum]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "minimum change for 69 with denomiations [25,10,5,1] by recursive : ",get_min_coin_configuration(69,[25,10,5,1])
    print "*"*45
    print "minimum change for 7 with denomiations [4,3,1] by recursive : ",get_min_coin_configuration(7,[4,3,1])
```

The program seems to work fine when I comment out either of the print statements in the main.
when I have both function calls, it is printing wrongly. comment out either print statements in the main and you would see that it prints the minimum coins correctly.

```
minimum change for 69 with denomiations [25,10,5,1] by recursive :  [25, 25, 10, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
*********************************************
minimum change for 7 with denomiations [4,3,1] by recursive :  [5, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cache_denom_set1 = {}
    cache_denom_set2 = {}
    print "minimum change for 69 with denomiations [25,10,5,1] by recursive : ",get_min_coin_configuration(69,[25,10,5,1],cache_denom_set1)
    print "*"*45
    print "minimum change for 7 with denomiations [4,3,1] by recursive : ",get_min_coin_configuration(7,[4,3,1],cache_denom_set2)
```

pass in a separate cache for each set of denominations

the problem is that your cache already knows how to make change for 7 as 5,1,1 so it just returns that ... the cache is unaware that 5 is no longer in the denomination set ...

dictionaries are mutable like lists ... this should demonstrate the problem

```
def dict_fn(cache={}):
    cache[len(cache.keys())] = 1
    print cache

dict_fn()
dict_fn()
```

Comment: But they are seperate calls, each one should have its own function object and initializes with empty cache..?

Comment: nope ... a dictionary is mutable you are pointing to the same dictionary ... (print cache at the top of the function) ... see edit

Comment: this means all the function object shares the same dict? which means a reference to it must be existing in some namespace, which namespace is that?