# behavior of default parameters in python function declaration?

Tags: python, function, arguments, default-parameters

I got this question from the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962428/unexpected-behaviour-in-this-program-in-python).

consider this code

```
def test(a,dict={}):
     b=5
     dict[a]=1
     print dict
     print locals()

test(1)

test(2)
```

The output is:

```
{1: 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'dict': {1: 1}}
{1: 1, 2: 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'dict': {1: 1, 2: 1}}
```

As I can infer, there is a "global" reference to the dict.

what is passed as default parameter to the function is persistent somewhere in the namespace.

It is shared across when the function is called again. but how do I know what the current `dict` holds. I can have a `dict` outside of the function and pass that `dict` to the function to know what the `dict` holds.

But my question is where  the default parameter of `dict` is present (in the namespace) and how to access it. when is this `dict` created? when the function is called first time or when the `def` statement is executed?

btw, printing the `locals()` shows that dict is local to function

Thanks

Comment: *Aside*: please don't name your variables after the type. The variable name makes the type name inaccessible, leading to hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Thanks for the note, I will follow this

Comment: Hmm, we may have been wrong to close as a dup.  From the OP's comment on the answer, the standard Q&A is certainly something that will help the OP understand what's going on, but the question about "where the default parameter of dict is present (in the namespace) and how to access it" is separate.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `test.func_defaults` or perhaps `test.__defaults__`. I think you'll find what you seek there.

Reference: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Comment: that helped, when is this `dict` created. is it when the function is called or when the def statement is executed?

Comment: The default arg is created once, when the `def` is executed. The function call merely binds the argument name to the already-existing default argument object.